# Weighted average resampling

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to resample a pandas dataset in Python, using weighted average method.
The code I am using:

```
etpa_hourlywa=etpa_data.resample("60Min").apply(lambda x: np.average(x['Price'],weights=x['Total quantity']))
```

Python gives the following error:

```
Weights sum to zero, can't be normalized
```

I have checked the weights for a few hours in my dataset (Total quantity column). They do not sum to zero when I check.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Are the weights at least all positive?

Comment: Yes, all weights are positive

Comment: Can you please post more of your code and sample data so we can try to find the error in your code? Please post a minimal reproducible example, that one can just copy and run it.